# Как добавить новый интерфейс linux?

Tags: linux, сервер, ssh, сеть

Здравствуйте! Есть сервер linux, к нему подсоединен ssh-туннель. Как добавить этот ssh-туннель в network/interfaces, что бы сервер видел его как дополнительный ip?

Так можно сделать через ipip туннель или pptp, но мне нужно именно через ssh. Так как есть 10 серверов, к которым я подключусь через ssh туннель и мне нужно добавить 10 интерфейсов с разными внешними айпишниками. Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать?

P.S: на серверах, к которым я подключаюсь по ssh ничего делать нельзя

Comment: Тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/87197/ пишут как поднимается туннель, но там требуется выполнение ifconfig на обоих сторонах соединения, т.е. вам нужен root доступ на оба хоста

Comment: так я умею делать. Это слишком просто, а в моем случае, невозможно. Я могу лишь сделать соединение через ssh или openssh или как-то сделать vpn из ssh туннеля(пока не знаю как). А мне нужно добавить внешний IP, который я получил из ssh соединения в etc/interfaces.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именно вам требуется. какова изначальная задача/проблема?

Comment: @bossuvarkin В вопрос добавьте какой у вас дистрибутив. в gentoo и debian я не нашел /etc/interfaces

Comment: mike, у меня дистрибутив debian/centos. Подскажите по тому, что знаете, я установлю нужную os

 
@alexander barakin, Условия: через ssh или openssh или любой друго способ я создаю туннель между серверами. Есть сервер (клиент), есть сервера ssh (10 шт). Задача:
нужно на сервере-клиенте добавить 10 интерфейсов, которые имею внешние айпишники серверов-ssh. Так можно сделать через ipip или pptp (ip туннель), НО на серверах ssh ничего нельзя делать (только подконнектится к ним можно)

Comment: мне подсказали, что ssh - это канальный уровень, а сетевой интерфейс - это сетевой уровень. И, как-бы, это типа плохо для моей задачи и я ничего не смогу сделать с этим(сделать связь между уровнями и перенести айпишник из ssh-туннеля в интерфейсы). Но я не думаю, что это невозможно. Должен быть какой-то способ... :(

Comment: @bossuvarkin, спасибо за повторное объяснение, но я спрашивал об *изначальной* задаче/проблеме: возможно, у неё есть иные решения, а не только то, что выбрано вами («добавить 10 интерфейсов»).

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/87197/

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать sshuttle: https://debian.pro/1747

Comment: создайте скрипты в иф-ап

Answer (score 2):

Перед тем, как запускать демон ssh в режиме Point - to - Point, вам необходимо заранее подготовить tun устройства для каждого сервера. Это можно сделать двумя путями:

1. Командой ip tuntap:

```
    ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
```

2. Держать устройства наготове, добавив в **/etc/systemd/network/** netdev устройство:

```
[NetDev]
Name=tun0
Kind=tun

#Разрешить доступ пользователям входящим в группу vpn
[Tun]
Group=vpn
```

И network файл:

```
[Match]
Name=tun0

[Address]
Address=172.17.0.1/30
Peer=172.17.0.2/30

[Network]
Address=172.17.0.1/30

[Route]
Gateway=172.17.0.1
Destination=192.168.1.0/24
```

Второй вариант более предпочтителен, так как:

- фаервол будет знать о наличии таких устройств
- Открывать тунель сможет непривигилерованный пользователь
- Вы сможете настроить маршруты заранее, а не прописывать их каждый раз когда хотите подключиться

[Руководство по поднятию тунеля непривигилерованными пользователями](http://influunt.ru/p2p-tunnel-with-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Можно на сервере собрать/загрузить slirp и поднять ppp через ssh (root не нужен)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slirp
http://math.arizona.edu/~swig/documentation/slirp/windows/win2000.php